# C# How do I create a Hyperlink OnClick event on GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble creating the GridView I want.
I would like the user to get inside the website and see the GridView which is attached to a DB.
Columns are: `ID, InsertionTime, Filepath, ProccessedByUser`
Now I want the user to click the filepath he/she would like to process. When he/she clicks the filepath, I want their username (logged in with built-in asp website authentication) to be updated (added) into DB.

My markup is standard and I haven't got to manage with code behind.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="starttime" HeaderText="starttime" 
            SortExpression="starttime" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="path" DataTextField="path" 
            HeaderText="path" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user" HeaderText="user" SortExpression="user" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried using HyperlinkField but it doesn't seem to support onlick events.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you are looking for the [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control which has an `OnClick` event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="starttime" HeaderText="starttime" 
            SortExpression="starttime" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Path" SortExpression="Filepath">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LbPath" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Filepath") %>'
                    CommandName="PathUpdate" 
                    CommandArgument='<%#Bind("path") %>'>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user" HeaderText="user" SortExpression="user" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now you can handle the `LinkButton's` [click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx) or the `GridView's` `RowCommand` event.

```
protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "PathUpdate")
    {
        string path= e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        // do you what you need to do
    }
}
```

Note that i've used a `TemplateField` which is the most dynamic column type in a `GridView` since you can add anything you want, even nested GridViews or `UserControls`.

Comment: Hey Tim! Thanks a lot! You solved my problem though I still want the LinkButton's Text to be a bound value. How can I do that? I tried `Bind()` but it's not allowed.

Comment: @Hedgie: Why do you want to use `Bind` instead of `Eval`? It is readonly anyway. Edited my answer to show how to use `Eval` on the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ButtonField, and then handle OnRowCommand of the gridview. Example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfieldbase.buttontype.aspx

You can set the ButtonType attribute of ButtonField to display the button as a Link.